# Partial AutoComplete in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I'm very happy with the way eclipse autocompletes for me, but I was wondering if it could do something more...

I often have very similarly named variables, such as `myPlayerManagerPane` and `myCharacterManagerPane`, I was wondering if there was a way that would allow me to get half way into the name, type a character or two and then autocomplete. This would let me copy and past lines of code for both, then surgically edit the variable names. It's gotten to the point where I'm trying to do this (I'm autocompleting on autopilot) and getting fun variables such as `myCharacterManagerPaneManagerPane` as I autocomplete a whole name, halfway through another.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist**, select "**Completion overwrites**", instead of "Completion inserts". This would overwrite the entire variable with the new one.

Alternatively, you can press `Ctrl` to toggle this behaviour when the content assist window pops up.

Answer (score 0):

Your question (or rather, its prelude) can easily be confused with another one; namely,

> Say I have two variables `variableLabel` and `variableConfiguration`, how can I have Eclipse complete the common prefix of the two variables, i.e. `variable`, before writing either `L` or `C` and having Eclipse "AutoComplete" complete the rest?

This is the question which lead me to this thread, so I feel I must answer it:

In **Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist**, check "Insert common prefixes automatically". Pressing `Ctrl+Space` now results in the desired functionality.

[Relevant StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824168/what-does-insert-common-prefixes-automatically-do-in-eclipse)